# Reading a film script in PDF and displaying it with correct format

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to read in from a PDF a film script and display it in the terminal with the correct line breaks however reading it in line by line doesn't seem to be working...

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import os.path

PDFInput = "Pulp-Fiction.pdf"

#checking if good
if "pdf" not in (PDFInput[-3:]):
    print("This isn't a pdf...")
    exit()

if os.path.isfile(PDFInput):
    print("it exists!")
else:
    print("This doesn't exist...")
    exit()


#opening file
with open(PDFInput, "rb") as PDFOpened: #this is my file object
    pdf = PdfFileReader(PDFOpened) #pdf is my reader object
    print ("This is the document infor: ", pdf.getNumPages())
    NumOfPage= pdf.getNumPages()
    print ("This is the document infor: ", pdf.getDocumentInfo())
    
    #eventually NumOfPage would go here but to keep compiling small
    for i in range(2): 
        pdfPage = pdf.getPage(i) #page object
        print ("page no: ", i)
        text = pdfPage.extractText().split('  ') #extracting and spliting text from page
    
    for i in range (len(text)): #lines stored in list and printed seprating
        print(text[0], end="\n")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the expected output is and what you are getting?

Comment: `PDF` is very complex file type - better use normal text file.

Comment: paisanco, so the biggest problem I'm receiving is for a lot of the line breaks nothing is added- this leads to words being merged together. Looking at it closely I can see that the 2nd line of a paragraph has a line break but the first and last do not.

Comment: K J, I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Does this mean there's no way I can correctly add breaks when reading in PDFs?

Comment: @KJ ah okay that makes more sense, do you have any advice on how I would go about reading PDF to at least make sure words aren't merged together?